# How to remove white space characters in between the string?

Tags: java

For example, I want to convert the string `test123 test124 test125`  to

`test123+""+test124+""+test125` or `test123test124test125`.

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: String newString = oldString.replaceAll(" ","");

Comment: Your question is unclear - it's not obvious whether test123 etc are *variables*, or text within an existing string. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help. It's also *very* unlikely that this is really Android-specific, so I'd suggest you stick to a regular Java console app.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
String output = inputText.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Comment: Awesome answer, this is what i exactly wanted.

Comment: Hi please could you explain why "\s" throws an error and also why the "+" is needed at the end?

Comment: @BlessenGeorge `+` matches one or more entry.  You need to escape `\` to represent `\s` because `\s` is not a valid escape sequence. Try `System.out.println("\\s")`

Answer (score 6):

use [`String.replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
"test123 test124 test125".replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: How can you do this to a whole array list of Strings? I want to get rid of the whitespace in each string element of an arraylist

Answer (score 3):

Use `String result = yourString.replace(" ","");`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the replace method of the string like

```
str.replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using String Tokeniser, simplest way is,

```
String s = "test123 test124 test125";        
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( s, " " );
while(st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    System.out.print(st.nextToken());
}
```